# select query performs wrong results on parallel execution

Tags: mysql

Following is my scenario

I have tables named

```
Products

id | name | count | Price 
-------------------------
 1 | meat |  1    |  10


Users

id | name | balance 
-----------------
 1 | Tim  |  10
 2 | Joe  |  10
```

Work flow

select products if count >= 1,
 reduce user's balance and count = count - 1 
 if no_balance or count < 1 throw error

Let's say if both users placing an order for 1 product at exact same time, products table count updates to -1, means query executes for both users.

Products

```
id | name | count | Price 
-------------------------
 1 | meat |  -1    |  10
```

During placeing of an order,I have used the below query to select matching products

```
Select * from products where count >= 1 and price >= 10
```

Also, if users place orders with even little time difference, the expecting output gathered.

Is there any solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider use `lock` for each row, for example.

Select * from products where count >= 1 and price >= 10 FOR UPDATE.

But in your scenario, I advice you use `Redis` to do that.

[How to design a second kill system for online shop](http://www.codeblogbt.com/archives/49156)